# How to set date formats and culture in asp.net core razor pages 2.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, date-formatting, razor-pages, culture

I'm using Asp.Net Core 2.2 Razor Pages application. I want to set application culture and date formats in application level. So after some googling I end up adding the below code in `ConfigureServices` method in **Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // setting the application culture to en-US with MM/dd/yyyy short date pattern.
            var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            var dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo { ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy", LongDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" };
            culture.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = culture;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = culture;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I'm getting the date in wrong format. Example,
`DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` returns **6/25/2019** instead of **06/25/2019**. The same is the problem with `DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString()`

And If I change the format to "dd/MM/yyyy" will it return the date in **25/06/2019**??

I'm running this in my local development environment. Also what I'm expecting is that my app to get the dates in the same format I set above in any environment, any machine, any culture.

Please assist and guide me on where I'm wrong.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Start from the docs [Globalization and localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2). You can set the request locale through [the localization middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#localization-middleware). You may need nothing more than a call to `app.UseRequestLocalization` with the culture you want

Comment: How to set the short date and long date formats while using `app.UseRequestLocalization` ??

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two questions here :

1. How to properly localize a web appication and
2. How to use a custom culture ?

ASP.NET Core and ASP.NET offer their own globalization and localization features that work on multiple levels (application, page, request). You should check [Globalization and Localization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to understand how these features work in ASP.NET Core. As everything else, the services are provided through middleware.

There are a lot of blog posts about this too. I picked this one due to the title [Internationalization - ASP.NET Core: From 0 to overkill](https://blog.codingmilitia.com/2019/04/24/aspnet-018-from-zero-to-overkill-internationalization). It explains the same things the docs do, in a more concise way.

For your specific question though, all that's needed is to set the culture for each request. This can be done [with the localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.2#localization-middleware) middleware's [UseRequestLocalization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.applicationbuilderextensions.userequestlocalization?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method.

In Startup.cs's `Configure(IApplicationBuilder, IWebHostEnvironment)`, right before `app.UseStaticFiles()` you can add a call to `UseRequestLocalization` to specify the cultures :

```
var supportedCultures = new[]
{
   new CultureInfo("ru-RU"),                

};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ru-RU"),
    SupportedCultures=supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures=supportedCultures
});
```

I picked `ru-RU` because it uses a dot for a date separator. Putting

```
@DateTime.Today.ToString()
```

in a Razor page this produces

```
25.06.2019 0:00:00
```

You can pass your own custom culture to `UseRequestLocalization` too. Using this custom culture :

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var dateformat = new DateTimeFormatInfo { 
    ShortDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy", 
    LongDatePattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt" 
};
culture.DateTimeFormat = dateformat;

var supportedCultures = new[]
{
    culture
};

app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions{
    DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(culture),
    SupportedCultures=supportedCultures,
    SupportedUICultures=supportedCultures
});
```

Produces :

```
06/25/2019 00:00:00
```

Comment: Hi @Panagiotis Thanks for the answer and great explanation. This works fine in code. But this is not working with ef core migrations. I have a some date fields with datetime values in my context `OnModelCreating` method and when I `Add-Migration` the dates that gets saved in database are in different format. Please assist.

Comment: @Abdul that's not what you asked. EF has nothing to do with web applications, it's an ORM. In any case, dates have *no* format, they are binary values. Formats apply only when *parsing* strings into dates or formatting the dates into strings. Perhaps you mistook the way a client tool displays dates for an actual format?

Comment: Yeah I'm little confused. I think I mistook as you said. I'm sorry I'm in learning phase.

Comment: @Abdul that's mainly Microsoft's fault - EF and ASP.NET Core are separate teams and used to have different repos. A couple of years ago they decided it's best to put EF under ASP.NET Core, even though it's not only about web development. That confused a *lot* of people and half the EF questions recently use the wrong tags.

Answer (score 3):

Your `WebApplication` use multiple threads, if you set a `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture` of your current thread, others may differ.

Try use `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` :

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = culture;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = culture;
```

Comment: This doesn't affect the request culture at all. ASP.NET Core has its own localization mechanism and will even detect the *browser's* preferred languages and use them to format data

Comment: I use this to set localization in my ASP.NET Core app.