# cultureInfo not work in production environment in linux-64 centos

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core

I set "cultureInfo"  in startup.cs > Configure like:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("xx-XX"); // xx-XX can be : fr-FR or fa-IR 
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

It's work truly in my localhost (win 10 & IIS express) and work true in my test machine (win server 2012 && IIS). but when i publish in Centos7 and nginx proxy it is not work and all cultureInfo set to default.

any one have any idea, why it is not work or have any experience how fix it?

update 1:

in view by this code:

```
<p>
     @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name
</p>
```

it's return true cultureInfo : xx-XX but in act not work (like datetime format)

update 2:
win10 && iis express:

[image]

centos & nginx proxy :

[image]

Comment: Have you checked application logs for any errors ?

Comment: yes it has not any error.

Comment: If you try to output the value of  `cultureInfo.LCID` in console or in a file, what it's value ?

Comment: return true culture name like "fa-IR"

Comment: Thanks for the update, it gives more info. Could you please post also also a specific example (for that datetime I get this, whereas I should get this) ?

Comment: I found this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56748968/how-to-set-date-formats-and-culture-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages-2-2, please have a look and let me know if it fixes your problem.

Comment: @Christos

this post not relate my problem, i have problem only in Linux environment.
add some screenshot, i hope useful

Comment: unless I am wrong, the ss seems same to me. Probably, you haven't posted twice one of them. Though first, I would suggest you try that is described in the first answer o the link, I sent you earlier.

Comment: i fix second photo. updated. thanks

Comment: You are welcome. Please try that is described in the link mentioned before and let me know.

Comment: it's not useful to solve problem