# Migrating from .NET Core 2 to .NET Core 7: Changes for Localization in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

I'm in the process of upgrading a .NET Core 2 application to .NET Core 7. As part of this upgrade, I'm specifically looking into the localization setup in the Startup.cs file.

I've used the following configuration for localization in .NET Core 2:

```
 services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en"),
                    new CultureInfo("ar"),
                    new CultureInfo("ar-AE"),
                    new CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
                    new CultureInfo("fr"),
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                };

                opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("ar-AE");
                // Formatting numbers, dates, etc.
                opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                // UI strings that we have localized.
                opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
                var defaultCookieRequestProvider =
                   opts.RequestCultureProviders.FirstOrDefault(rcp =>
                       rcp.GetType() == typeof(CookieRequestCultureProvider));
                if (defaultCookieRequestProvider != null)
                    opts.RequestCultureProviders.Remove(defaultCookieRequestProvider);
                opts.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0,
                   new CookieRequestCultureProvider()
                   {
                       CookieName = ".AspNetCore.Culture",
                       Options = opts
                   });
            });
            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            services.AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization((LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix))
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization(options =>
                {
                    options.DataAnnotationLocalizerProvider = (type, factory) =>
                    {
                        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(SharedResource).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);
                        return factory.Create("SharedResources", assemblyName.Name);
                    };
                });
```

```
      var locOptions = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
            app.UseRequestLocalization(locOptions.Value);
```

View

```
@SharedHtmlLocalizer["index"]
```

However, I'm unsure about the necessary changes I need to make to accommodate the migration to .NET Core 7. Specifically, regarding the changes needed for setting up localization in the updated Startup.cs.

I've reviewed the migration guides and documentation but would appreciate more specific insights or pointers for adjusting the localization setup in the new version. Are there any significant changes in the way localization is handled in .NET Core 7 that I should consider during this migration?

Comment: This answer may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56749905/2181514

Comment: once you've configured  RequestLocalizationOptions before IServiceCollection build,you could just call app.UseRequestLocalization() without reading the options from container